# How does passing Objective-C object as argument to C++ method work?

Tags: c++, webkit, objective-c++

I was reading source code of WebKit yesterday when I found some lines of  code that I can't understand how it works.

There is a C++ method declared in `WebPageProxy.h` as this:

```
RefPtr<API::Navigation> loadRequest(const WebCore::ResourceRequest&, WebCore::ShouldOpenExternalURLsPolicy = WebCore::ShouldOpenExternalURLsPolicy::ShouldAllowExternalSchemes, API::Object* userData = nullptr);
```

It is called in `WKWebView.mm` like this:

```
- (WKNavigation *)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    auto navigation = _page->loadRequest(request);
    if (!navigation)
        return nil;

    return [wrapper(*navigation.leakRef()) autorelease];
}
```

The argument `request` is of type `NSURLRequest *`, but the type in the declaration of the method is `const WebCore::ResourceRequest&`. I can't fully understand it.

Also, after setting some breakpoints and experimenting, I found that this constructor of the `ResourceRequest` class is being called:

```
ResourceRequest(NSURLRequest *nsRequest)
: ResourceRequestBase()
, m_nsRequest(nsRequest)
{
}
```

I'm not familiar with C++. Can someone help me understand how does this work?

Comment: Not that hard to understand. `loadRequest()` expects a reference to a const `ResourceRequest` object, but is being passed an `NSURLRequest*` pointer instead. `ResourceRequest` has a constructor that accepts a `NSURLRequest*` as input, so the compiler is constructing a temporary `ResourceRequest` object to pass to `loadRequest()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is this a feature of C++? where can I learn more about this feature?

Comment: yes, this is a feature of C++. Any decent C++ book/tutorial covers constructors and implicit conversions. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: oh, I see. After some google, it turns out C++ can do this kind of implicit conversion if the target class type declares appropriate converting constructor.